# Count with a subselect yielding double the amount

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I'm new to SQL.

*Problem*: Say if I were to count the amount that is contained in the alias table of "x" `COUNT(x.xValue)` to be 217. Now when I add the sub-query "y" and then do the count again, I have the `COUNT(x.xValue)` to suddenly square its self -> 47089. Why is this happening?

(Note: Both alias tables "x" and "y" have the same amount -> 217.)

How do I fix this problem. I don't want to use Variables or Views.

```
SELECT COUNT(x.xValue) + COUNT(y.yValue) AS CountXY
FROM 
(SELECT value AS xValue FROM table1
            WHERE 
            ...) AS x,
(SELECT value AS yValue FROM table1 
            WHERE 
            ...) AS y
```

Result of 'CountXY' : 94178.

Result I'm expecting 'CountXY' : 434

Comment: What you wrote there is called a theta-join or "the old way of doing joins". Every row of table `x` will be joined to every row of table `y`. If both tables contain 217 rows, you'll get what you said `x * y`. Since x and y in your case are both 217, you get the square of 217. What you actually want is `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE..) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE..) AS my_total_count)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing two sub-queries and then trying to call the values return directly.

This will behave as selecting one value from table `x` and matching it to every single value in table `y`. This obviously creates the *squared return* effect.

What you need to use is the `JOIN` to combine both *data-sets* so that you get the `1 to 1` relationship you are trying to achieve.

This is how the above should be done with your previous sub-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.value) AS x, COUNT(B.value) AS y
FROM table1 AS A
    JOIN table1 AS B
        ON A.attr1 = B.attr1
        AND A.attr2 = B.attr2
    WHERE B.attr1 != 'whatever'
    AND B.attr2 = 'whatever'
    AND A.attr3 = 'something'
    AND B.attr3 = 'something different'
```

The above query should return the correct `1 to 1` relationship you are looking for. Replacing your sub-query with the one above should give you the correct answer